# Maximo Processing rule to skip update a part of the xml

Tags: maximo

I am trying to create a processing rule which will skip only part of the incoming xml . For eg i want to skip email updates if the email id already exists in database and process the rest of the message.
Need some inputs on the same.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the XML? It will also help us if you read and apply [ask] and [example].

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncPERSON xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" creationDateTime="" baseLanguage="EN" transLanguage="EN" maximoVersion="7.5" messageID="">
  <PERSONSet>
    <PERSON>
      <PERSONID></PERSONID>
      <STATUS></STATUS>
      <FIRSTNAME></FIRSTNAME>
      <LASTNAME></LASTNAME>
      <DEPARTMENT></DEPARTMENT>
      <JOBCODE></JOBCODE>
      <PERSONUID></PERSONUID>
      <LANGCODE></LANGCODE>
      <PRIMARYPHONE></PRIMARYPHONE>
      <PRIMARYEMAIL></PRIMARYEMAIL>
      <SUPERVISOR></SUPERVISOR>
    </PERSON>
  </PERSONSet>
</SyncPERSON>

Comment: sample xml posted above

Comment: You should edit your question to include the sample XML in a human-legible format. Using Help, you could find that you can start a code block by putting 3 back-ticks followed by the language name on the line before your code, and you can end the block by putting 3 back-ticks on the line after your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying skip the email update in the inbound processing xml by setting it to null for PERSON object structure. Following is my code.Can someone tell me what is wrong with it:

```
  from java.util import *
  from psdi.mbo import *
  from java.lang import *
  from psdi.server import MXServer
  def beforeCreateMboSet(ctx):
  mbo = ctx.getMbo()
  struc = ctx.getData()
  try:
   emailSet =MXServer.getMXServer().getMboSet('PRIMARYEMAIL')
   eCount = emailSet.count()
   while eCount!=0:
    primaryemail=struc.getCurrentData('PRIMARYEMAIL')
    emailMbo=emailSet.getMbo(eCount)
    if emailMbo is not None:
      email=emailMbo.getString("EMAILADDRESS")
      if(primaryemail.upper() == email.upper()):
       struc.setCurrentDataNull('PRIMARYEMAIL')
   finally:
     emailSet.close()
```

Following is my incoming XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncPERSON xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" creationDateTime=""      baseLanguage="EN" transLanguage="EN" maximoVersion="7.5" messageID="">
<PERSONSet>
<PERSON>
  <PERSONID></PERSONID>
  <STATUS></STATUS>
  <FIRSTNAME></FIRSTNAME>
  <LASTNAME></LASTNAME>
  <DEPARTMENT></DEPARTMENT>
  <EMPLOYEETYPE></EMPLOYEETYPE>
  <JOBCODE></JOBCODE>
  <PERSONUID></PERSONUID>
  <LANGCODE></LANGCODE>
  <PRIMARYPHONE></PRIMARYPHONE>
  <PRIMARYEMAIL></PRIMARYEMAIL>
  <SUPERVISOR></SUPERVISOR>
</PERSON>
</PERSONSet>
```